# How to unite two polygons so that output is polygon not path (javafx)?

Tags: javafx, path, union, polygon

I have two Polygon class objects that I want to unite using union() method from javafx.scene.shape.Shape and I need the output to also be Polygon class object. I have found several examples where the output is Path object:

```
Path path = Path.union(shape1, shape2)
```

Or is it possible to convert Path to Polygon? I tried to google it but with no luck.

Comment: Why does the output need to be a Polygon class object?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson We have a program that is visualising these polygons on the scene. The united polygon should be a Polygon class object to be able to interpret all the other rules and conditions that have been set up for the Polygon class objects.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use Path. I think they built Path.union with the idea that if you union two shapes of the same type the result will not be a shape of the original type. Example Polygon union Polygon != Polygon. With that said. I think you should create you own union method. That takes two Polygons and return a Polygon that fits your ideas.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Actually union(shape1, shape2) is a method from class Shape. In the API I could not find a clue about why this method returns a Path type object, not Polygon or Circle or anything else..

Comment: Actually, union returns a Shape object. The reason it does not return a Circle or Polygon is because if you union two shapes of the same type, you are not guaranteed to get a shape of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take the union of two polygons then you get a Path object as you stated. It is possible to convert this path object into a Polygon object (not the nicest code but doable).

```
//createing both polygon objects p1 and p2
Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
p1.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            0.0, 0.0,
            20.0, 10.0,
            10.0, 20.0 });

Polygon p2 = new Polygon();
p2.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            10.0, 0.0,
            25.0, 10.0,
            5.0, 20.0 });

// Taking the union that results in a Path object
Path p3 = (Path) Polygon.union(p1, p2);

// Array of points for the new polygon
Double[] points = new Double[(p3.getElements().size() - 1)*2];

int i = 0;
// going through all the path elements in the path and adding the x and y coordinates to points
for(PathElement el : p3.getElements()){
    if(el instanceof MoveTo){
        MoveTo mt = (MoveTo) el;
        points[i] = mt.getX();
        points[i+1] = mt.getY();
    }
    if(el instanceof LineTo){
        LineTo lt = (LineTo) el;
        points[i] = lt.getX();
        points[i+1] = lt.getY();
    }
    i += 2;
}

// creating new Polygon with these points
Polygon newPolygon = new Polygon();
newPolygon.getPoints().addAll(points);
```

This might not work if the polygons do not intersect, but should work otherwise. If there is no intersection you will have two MoveTo statements instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I am talking about.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class JavaFXApplication31 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
        p1.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            60.0, 60.0,
            80.0, 70.0,
            70.0, 80.0 });

        Polygon p2 = new Polygon();
        p2.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            40.0, 40.0,
            60.0, 50.0,
            50.0, 60.0 });        

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();


        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Click me!'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Polygon unioned!");
                Shape union = Polygon.union(p1, p2);
                union.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                root.getChildren().add(union);
            }
        });

        Button btn2 = new Button();
        btn2.setText("New Polygon union!'");
        btn2.setLayoutX(100);
        btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Polygon p3 = createNewPolygonUnion(p1, p2);
                p3.setFill(Color.RED);
                root.getChildren().add(p3);
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(p1, p2, btn, btn2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    Polygon createNewPolygonUnion(Polygon one, Polygon two)
    {
        Polygon p3 = new Polygon();

        ArrayList<Double> onePoints = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Double> twoPoints = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Double> threePoints = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < one.getPoints().size(); i++)
        {
            onePoints.add(one.getPoints().get(i));   
            twoPoints.add(two.getPoints().get(i));            
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < onePoints.size(); i++)
        {
            threePoints.add(onePoints.get(i) + twoPoints.get(i));
        }

        p3.getPoints().addAll(threePoints);

        return p3;
    }
}
```

> Original two polygons.

[image]

> Union of the two original polygons. The union of the two polygons does not
>   result in a polygon.

[image]

> Union from a method I created. This method uses the points from the
>   original two polygons and create a new polygon.

[image]